# Build multiple sources into multiple targets in a directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

folks. I'm learning about GNU-Make and I have the following project structure:

```
~/projects
    /sysCalls
        ex1.c
        ex2.c
        ex3.c
        ex4.c
        ex5.c
        ex6.c
        ex7.c
```

Each `.c` source is very simple, has its own `main` function and must be built into a corresponding binary (preferably named after its source). But I want to build into a `bin` directory (added to my `.gitignore` file).

My current Makefile is:

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -g
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
TARGET := $(SRC:.c=)

all: bin $(TARGET)
    mv $(TARGET) bin/

bin:
    mkdir bin

clean:
    rm -fr bin/
```

It works as expected, but always builds every source. And I don't like moving everything to `bin` "manually".

Any tips or ideas on how this Makefile could be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Etan Reisner answer I've found what I think it's the solution.

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -g
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
TARGET := $(SRC:%.c=bin/%)

all: | bin $(TARGET)

bin/% : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

bin:
    mkdir bin

clean:
    rm -fr bin/
```

The key was to use the `bin/% : %.c` rule.

Comment: order-only on `$(TARGET)` is probably not what you actually want (though it may not make much of a difference for a target like `all` here).

Comment: Your `bin/%` rule also is missing a space between `$<` and `-o`. That being said you might be able to avoid needing that rule at all by using `vpath` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `TARGET` line with

```
TARGET := $(addprefix bin/,$(SRC:.c=))
```

and add (with an appropriate compilation/linking rule)

```
bin/%: %.c
```

And `make` will still build any binaries that aren't up-to-date and `make bin/ex1` will build just that single binary both directly in the `bin` directory.

The order of operations on the `all` target is not robust in the face of the `-j` argument.

For GNU make this is what [`order-only prerequisites`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) are for.

Comment: Thanks! You answer put me in the right direction. But appending the /bin to the TARGET only worked for the first item. I had to use $(addprefix ...) function.

Comment: `$(addprefix bin/,$(SRC:.c=))` can be replaced by `$(SRC:%.c=bin/%)`.